# map a rectangle of my desktop to ~hdmi or ~vnc/rdp, including mouse/pen

Tags: vnc, wacom

<detailing a bit more of what I'm trying to accomplish to avoid X:Y problem>

I must mark up (pen) numerous images, saving off the marked-up ~`png`s both in-place or into another document.  The source images come from a mix of internal, vendor, and web sources; frequently I'm annotating just a small part of a very large image where I need to simultaneously see the whole image at once, and zoom into one corner to pen proposed changes.

It would be ideal if I could just "stream" a small rectangle of my desktop to a hdmi-drawing-tablet (or separate Surface tablet).

Primary work is done on my desktop/workstation as I need the context/screen size and ergonomic setup - it's not feasible for me to buy an LCD drawing *monitor*/tablet and simply open the entire source material there, such as when I am zoom to a tiny section but need the broader context.

**Desired solution:**

I envision/desire a workflow to "map" a rectangle of my desktop (as you'd select a rectangle [capturing a gif](https://youtu.be/w7oxaZuDjuc?t=14) with `Peek`) onto **either**

- my Surface (via something akin to `VNC`),
- or to it's own ~window (which can then be viewed(mirrored) on another monitor, specifically a drawing tablet over hdmi)

A simpler but similar example would be how [Flameshot screen capture](https://flameshot.org/) works, just with a pen **on an external device**, not mouse on my existing monitor:
[image: flameshot screenshot-with-markup demo]

presently I'm on Ubuntu `20.04` (`x11`) but we'll be upgraded to `22.04` (`wayland`) later this year.  Tiling window manager `i3wm`.